# What ECMAScript 5 'use strict' string costs exist?

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-5

What is meant by 'use strict' string costs in  [almond.js](https://github.com/jrburke/almond/blob/master/almond.js) line 6?

A Google returns no information on the issue the author seems to be implying.

Comment: +1. Crossposted as a note on the commit: https://github.com/jrburke/almond/commit/c9657f26d25a956683aee0a69d60052bd7fc7a89#L1R6

Answer (score 13, accepted):

And the answer [is apparently](https://github.com/jrburke/almond/commit/c9657f26d25a956683aee0a69d60052bd7fc7a89#L1R6):

> It is extra bytes to deliver the 'use strict' string in the source, and this is trying to be a small library. So, just a way to reduce file size by a little bit.

Which is a pretty silly "cost". It's 13 bytes before compression -- that's insignificant.

Comment: Thanks for that! I wholly agree that it seems to be over the top. I had thought there might be some execution cost of some sort worth avoiding.

Comment: To be fair, that's actually an incomplete copy of what he said. He also references a risk (which is a type of cost) involving concatenating scripts, as described further in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Strict_mode_for_scripts